# How can I prevent my cursor from moving when I click the trackpad? (Macbook Pro + Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mouse

I just installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my Macbook Pro. When I click the trackpad, it is always registered as a small mouse movement as well as a click, so it drags whatever I click on. has anybody else encountered this? Is there any synaptics setting that can help? For the moment, I've enabled tap to click because normal clicking is so tough.

I didn't have this issue when running Ubuntu in a VM, but I guess that has another abstraction layer that prevents synaptics from being the one interpreting direct touchpad input.

Thanks!

Comment: [This question](http://superuser.com/questions/229839/reduce-laptop-touch-pad-sensitivity-in-ubuntu) and [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/128023/synaptics-touchpad-sensitivity-issue) should help.

Comment: that helped for the tap clicks (which were sometimes giving me trouble), but I can't seem to adjust the values so that I can click without the cursor moving and still move the cursor intentionally without an unreasonably high amount of pressure.

Comment: I think this question worth an answer, but in askubuntu